# How to efficiently determine if a set of points contains two that are close

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I need to determine if a set of points (each given by a tuple of floats, each of which is in [0, 1]) contains two that are within some threshold, say 0.01, of each other. I should also mention that in the version of the problem that I am interested in, these "points" are given by tuples of length ~30, that is they are points in [0, 1]^30.

I can test if any two are within this threshold using something like:

```
def is_near(p1, p2):
    return sqrt(sum((x1 - x2)**2 for x1, x2 in zip(p1, p2))) < 0.01  # Threshold.
```

Using this I can just check every pair using something like:

```
def contains_near(points):
     from itertools import combinations
     return any(is_near(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in combinations(points, r=2))
```

However this is quadratic in the length of the list, which is too slow for the long list of points that I have.

> Is there an n log n way of solving this?

I tried doing things like snapping these points to a grid so I could use a dictionary / hash map to store them:

```
def contains_near_hash(points):
     seen = dict()
     for point in points:
         # The rescaling constant should be 1 / threshold.
         grid_point = tuple([round(x * 100, 0) for x in point])  
         if grid_point in seen:
             for other in seen[grid_point]:
                 if is_near(point, other):
                      return True
             seen[grid_point].append(point)
         else:
             seen[grid_point] = [point]
    return False
```

However this doesn't work when

```
points = [(0.1149999,), (0.1150001,)]
```

As these round to two different grid points. I also tried a version in which the point was appended to all neighbouring grid points however as the examples that I want to do have ~30 coordinates, each grid point has 2^30 neighbours which makes this completely impractical.

Comment: The idea of using a grid is right and the common approach is to use R-tree to store points. Moreover your problem is well-known and called "Fixed-radius near neighbors"

Comment: A small optimization: don't call `sqrt()` in `is_near()`, use the squared distance instead.

Comment: @PM2Ring - sure, but the focus of the question is really about the asymptotic run time.

Comment: @qwerty1793: Understood! But that's why I said it was a small optimization.  :) And why I mentioned it in a comment rather than as an actual answer.

Comment: You might want to mention the fact that your real data has ~30 coordinates earlier in your question. As you've noticed, there's a big difference between 2 or 3 dimensions and 20 or 30 dimensions for problems like this (and 2000 or 3000 dimensions is yet another challenge entirely). Look up ["curse of dimensionality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) for some background.

Answer (score 7):

A pair of points can only be 'near' each other if their distance in at least one dimension is less than the threshold. This can be exploited to reduce the number of candidate pairs by filtering one dimension after the other.

I suggest:
- sort the points in one dimension (say: x)
- find all points which are close enough to the next point in the sorted list and put their index into a `set` of candidates
- do not use `sqrt()` but the quadratic distance `(x1 - x2)**2` or even `abs(x1 - x2)` for efficiency
- do that for the second dimension as well
- determine the intersect of both sets, these are points near each other

This way, you avoid costly `is_near()` calls, operate on way smaller sets, only work with unique points, and set lookups are very efficient.

This scheme can easily be expanded to include more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: FWIW, I use this approach in 3D to find nearest colors for palette mapping (in C rather than Python, so I don't have code to share). IME it works well, and I expect that it will work well for 30D tuples as well.

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting (and substantially different) approach. However if I do this for the first, second, ... dimension and get these lists of indices nearby points doesn't taking the intersection take O(n) and so I still end up with a quadratic algorithm in the worst case?

Comment: I guess the requirement for points to be close is even stronger: a pair of points can only be close if the difference along **all** dimensions is closer than the threshold. This means that when checking for the second or higher dimension, you only have to consider the candidates that survived the check for the previous dimensions.

Comment: @Bas: actually, that's what I meant...didn't come across at all. The main point is to filter or reduce the number of candidates before going into full distance calculation.

Comment: @qwerty1793: operations on sets (in Python, that is) are O(logn) - membership and thus intersection. I'm not into too deep with the implementation of sets but that's what I've read often. Internally, sets are hash lists.

Comment: Hmmm, https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set says that s.intersect(t) is O(min(len(s), len(t)) in the average case and O(len(s) * len(t)) in the worst case. Where have you read that they are O(log n)?

Comment: As deeper digging reveals (e.g. [link](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt) ) the `in` operation is of order O(1). Set inclusion will then be of order O(n) like you've cited. Although far from O(nlogn) it looks more promising than O(n*n).

Comment: There is no need for set operations. For each dimension, you do a sort, which is `O(n*log(n))`. You then do a single pass along the sorted result and copy the points that are close to a list of candidates. This is `O(n)`. For the next dimension, you just sort the list of remaining candidates, which might get smaller for each dimension. The time for the sort dominates, for an overall cost of `O(ndim*n*log(n))`. But in the end, you still have to do a check the real distance with `is_near()`, which costs `O(n_candidates^2)`. So worst case, it is still `O(n^2)`.